# How to access one web application from another web application (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have two web applications in jsp:

- 1st application is running on tomcat 6
- 2nd is running on tomcat 7 which resides on different machine

now I want to call the jsp of 2nd web application from 1st web application and also want to pass some data during run-time.

So how can I achieve that, please suggest me some solution.

Comment: How do you want to communicate with each other? You could do it through ajax calls from the client-side directly, or do remote calls from the server-side

Comment: @RaulRene: Note: AJAX only works if the domain is the same (Same Origin Policy).

Comment: Just access the other JSP using its URL.

Comment: @uma_SF In many products we need to integrate different services into a same product so we need this feature to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It was very simple both will be running on some URL alone so redirect that to other. The major thing you should concentrate on the passing data should accomplish a same data store i.e., both should point a same database or any other data storing technique. You have to design a database such that both should use the same data without any conflict.

[image]

If you want to use without any central repo you can pass the data by building it on an XML,JSON or any other technique that can act as a data carrier between two applications.

Comment: @hashokramcse thanks for your reply. I wil check this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access JSPs on a different server for various reasons (security among one of them).

What you can do:

1. Use an `iframe` to display a remote URL inline
2. Use a HTTP client library on one server to access the second server via HTTP
3. Add a JSON servlet to the second server which gives you access to the data you need. This allows you to use JSONP to access the data directly from the client or to process it with a JSON framework on the first server.

Comment: thank you for reply. can you please give me some information about how to use JSON servlet and JSON framework.

Comment: Refer this about JSON

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/
 and
http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: A JSON servlet is a normal servlet (you can even use JSP to implement it) which returns data in JSON format (and not HTML). In the past years, JSON has become a simple standard to exchange data easily without the overhead of web services, XML and other technologies.

Comment: @ashokramcse thanks. i will refer those links and ill try to implement that.